# JQuery validate and error on other form post

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a shopping cart form which has a coupon code field where user enter the coupon and i validate whether it is blank. On the same form, i also has a separate button which will trigger stripe pop up credit card payment box. When i finish the credit card payment,
the coupon code text box trigger an "required field" error which it shouldn't.

```
 <form action="/cart/" method="post" id="promotion-form" name="submit_promotion">
      <textarea placeholder="Enter promotional code" class="promotional-box" name="code" id="code"></textarea> 
      <input type="hidden" value="1" name="plan_id" id="plan_id">
     <button class="btn-apply pull-right" name="promotion-submit" type="submit">Apply</button>
                        </form>
```

JQuery

```
$('#promotion-form').validate(
        {
            rules: {
                code: {
                    minlength: 5,
                    required: true
                }

            },
            highlight: function(element) {
                $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
            },
            success: function(element) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: This isn't standard jQuery - I presume you're using a plugin? which one?

Comment: How does this question involve PHP?

Answer (score 0):

$("#promotion-form").click(function(){
    $("input.code").each(function(){
        $(this).rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: {
                required: "Code required."
            }
        } );
    });
    });